# R programming (Monte Carlo Simulation)

Tags: r, programming-languages, simulation, montecarlo

Hi I would like to ask how to sample out 50 instances of iris data (which contain 150 instances) by using Monte Carlo Simulation ?
Any idea? 
Many thanks

Comment: `iris[sample.int(nrow(iris),50),]` ? Your question is very broad though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sample_n` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) to select 50 rows with replacement.

```
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12800)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris_sub <- iris %>% sample_n(size = 50, replace = TRUE)
```

And here I show one approach that can repeat this process for 1000 times, using `map_dfr` from the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package. The end result is a data frame with 50000 rows. A new column called `Time` is created to document the number of sampling.

```
iris_sample <- map_dfr(1:1000, ~iris %>%
                         sample_n(size = 50, replace = TRUE) %>%
                         mutate(Time = .x))
```

Comment: If I want sample out 50 rows from iris data using Morte Carlo Simulation I just use the 1st one or  I use the second code by modify it repeating 50 times and every time only take 1 sample. </br>    iris_sample <- map_dfr(1:50, ~iris %>%
                         sample_n(size = 1, replace = TRUE) %>%
                         mutate(Time = .x))

Comment: @TwkWeiKeong Are you asking me a question which one you should use or are you saying that this is what you want to do? I guess what you are proposing is fine. If this answer solved your question, please consider to accept it.

Comment: I'm asking which one should I pick. Is it both method are similar? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, they are similar to me. The first one is better in terms of computation time and code simplicity.

Comment: Can I ask you 1 more question? I wan sample out 50 instances out of 150 iris data by using Jackknife resampling. Is it possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834613/using-jackknife-to-sample-out-iris-data-in-r?noredirect=1#comment86684576_49834613

Comment: Not sure what do you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it in base R.

You can sample 50 rows with replacement with

```
iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), size = 50, replace = TRUE), ]
```

To make a list, e.g., of 1000 samples of 50 rows with replacement, you can use `lapply`.

```
iris_mc_samps <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), size = 50, replace = TRUE), ])
```